# Entity Framework Code First Use foreign key as part of composite primary key

Tags: ef-code-first, foreign-keys, entity-framework-migrations

Using Code First, I created a model representing a `Donor`. I used a migration to generate a table to store all the `Donor` objects. I used annotations to specify the primary key to be a composite of two properties of my model, `Name` and `TeamId`.

I added a navigation property to the model called `HourlySnapshots` which is an `ICollection<HourlySnapshot>` representing a one-to-many relationship. (`HourlySnapshot` is another domain model I created.) I ran the migration and it generated another table to store all the `HourlySnapshot` objects. As expected, it added two columns that weren't in my model to store the foreign key composed of `Name` and `TeamId`.

In order to initialize the HourlySnapshots table, I included a conventional `Id` property in the `HourlySnapshot` object to be used as a primary key. What I'm trying to do is switch the primary key of the HourlySnapshots table from the `Id` column to a composite of the foreign key (which is a composite of `Name` and `TeamId`) and another property of `HourlySnapshot` called `Timestamp`. In other words, make it a composite of three columns `Name`, `TeamId`, and `Timestamp`.

Can you think of a way to do this with Code First? I can easily do this by opening the table definition and editing there, but I would like to adhere to the Code First workflow, so that the migrations include all the changes.

Comment: If you include your model code it is easier for people to assist. Second, [surrogate keys](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surrogate_key) make this much easier. But if you want natural keys you can specify composite keys in EF through [annotations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj591583(v=vs.113).aspx) or [fluently](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj591617(v=vs.113).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

After some more research, I was able to accomplish this with the Fluent API. I don't think it's possible using annotations or conventions. Here is what I ended up with in my `ApplicationDBContext` class...

```
public DbSet<Donor> Donors { get; set; }
public DbSet<HourlySnapshot> HourlySnapshots { get; set; }
public DbSet<DailySnapshot> DailySnapshots { get; set; }

protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Donor>()
        .HasKey(d => new { d.Name, d.TeamId });

    modelBuilder.Entity<HourlySnapshot>()
        .HasKey(s => new { s.Name, s.TeamId, s.Timestamp });

    modelBuilder.Entity<Donor>()
        .HasMany(d => d.HourlySnapshots)
        .WithOptional()
        .HasForeignKey(s => new { s.Name, s.TeamId });

    modelBuilder.Entity<DailySnapshot>()
        .HasKey(s => new { s.Name, s.TeamId, s.TimeStamp });

    modelBuilder.Entity<Donor>()
        .HasMany(d => d.DailySnapshots)
        .WithOptional()
        .HasForeignKey(s => new { s.Name, s.TeamId });

    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```